Delete closed Polylines in AutoCAD
I'm Trying to delete all Plines that are not closed in a certain layer.
But my code is not working.
I get an error Type Mistype at  If LWobj.Closed = False And LWobj.Layer = "0_String" Then
The Layer "0_String" Exists in drawing and LWobj closed state is derive correctly.
Sub clean()

Dim LWobj As AcadLWPolyline

For Each LWobj In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
    If LWobj.Closed = False And LWobj.Layer = "0_String" Then
        LWobj.Delete
        ThisDrawing.Regen acActiveViewport
    End If
Next

End Sub


You defined LWobj as AcadLWPolyline but not every object in Modelspace will be of type AcadLWPolyline.

Thanks, I'm new to the AutoCAD methods and objects, I need to learn it more.

The issue is that you have defined LWobj as an AcadLWPolyline, but not all objects in the Modelspace container will be of type AcadLWPolyline.
Instead, you should either use a selection set filter to acquire a set of only LWPolyline objects, or define LWobj as an AcadEntity and then check the object type along with your other conditions.
For example:
Dim ent As AcadEntity
For Each ent In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
    If TypeOf ent Is AcadLWPolyline Then
        If ent.Closed = False And ent.Layer = "0_String" Then
            ent.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next

You also don't want to be performing a regen with every iteration!
